# Postgres how to add new boolean column to table as a dependency of other boolean column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm working with my web app, using Rails and Angular. I have a old version of Rails API, where in the table there is a column named 'active'. There is a checkbox with this boolean value on the view. But the problem is that I want to migrate from 'active' to 'passive' word in the view, so I need to invert the current boolean value of 'active'. As I have a stable working version of old API, I can't invert this as usual. I need to create another column in my table (called 'passive') as dependency of 'active' column because I want to add new functionality and don't want to broke older one. How can I simply realize it ? I'm using postgres.

Comment: Because I have a mobile version and I need to work with both old and new version of API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in three steps all from the postgres db side.

1: Create the passive boolean column.

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN passive boolean;
```

2: Populate the new passive column based on the active column.

```
UPDATE foo SET passive = CASE WHEN active is true THEN false ELSE true END;
```

3: Create a trigger to maintain the passive boolean.

Define trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_passive() RETURNS trigger AS $set_passive$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.active is true THEN
       NEW.passive := false;
    ELSE
       NEW.passive := true;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Set trigger on table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_maintain_passive
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_passive();
```